# iOS only project contains My Mac as run destination

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating to Xcode 11, a framework project, with an iOS only dependency, has started to fail building from command line.

Initially it failed with:
`error: Building for Mac Catalyst requires macOS 10.15 or later. (in target 'X iOS' from project 'X')`

Changing `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST` to `NO` it fails with:

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build project X with scheme X iOS.
    Reason: The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'X iOS'.
```

And sure enough `My Mac` is listed in the possible run destinations.

How can I get this removed?

Comment: Just pick an iOS destination and ignore the My Mac destination.

Comment: `xcodebuild -scheme "X iOS"` fails. Anyhow with Catalyst disabled `My Mac` should disappear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the culprit turns out to be a test target that had `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST = YES`. If just a single target in your project has `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST` set to `YES` then `My Mac` will show up.

Answer (score 10):

I've had a similar issue. What worked for me was setting:

```
SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = "iphonesimulator iphoneos";
```

As well as setting:

```
SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST = NO;
DERIVE_MACCATALYST_PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = NO;
```

It did not work the first time, but it worked after I switched the ***Support Mac Catalyst*** option from ***NO*** to ***YES*** and back to ***NO*** again.

Comment: Yes, I encountered the same issue on my side. Might be an Xcode bug or the fact that I'm running Mojave.